# Junit ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, web-applications, junit

When i try to run a junit test individually i get this error. And when i try to run it using Ant(Which runs all the tests) it runs fine. Can anyone tell me what can be the possible reason? The src folder and the test folder are in same hierarchy. Do i have to link src and test folder?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.brinkmat.dao.impl.OwnerUtilsTest.testModifyOwnerAccount(OwnerUtilsTest.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.brinkmat.dao.utils.DumpLogger.<init>(DumpLogger.java:26)
at com.brinkmat.dao.utils.DumpLogger.getInstance(DumpLogger.java:34)
at com.brinkmat.deploy.Helper.<clinit>(Helper.java:64)
... 25 more

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.brinkmat.deploy.Helper
at com.brinkmat.dao.impl.OwnerUtilsTest.tearDown(OwnerUtilsTest.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: `Could not initialize class com.brinkmat.deploy.Helper` <-- this is what you should fix

Comment: `com.brinkmat.dao.utils.DumpLogger.<init>(DumpLogger.java:26)` This is the cause, what is the code there ?

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment environment = RuntimeEnvironment.getRuntimeEnvironment();
     String logFile = "log4j." + environment + ".properties";
     logFile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(logFile).getFile();
     PropertyConfigurator.configure(logFile); This code is there .

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like some property files are read by ant and not by your unit tests. If you are using spring, you can easily add properties by running with the spring junit class runner and setting properties there:

add things above your unit test's class declaration:

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "myconfig.xml" })

and add add your spring bean configuration (myconfig.xml or whatever you want to call it) in the classpath with your unit test. Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" >
        <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties">
                <value>
                   property1=value1
                   property2=value2
                   {etc...}
                </value>
                </property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment my first guess would be that the file "log4jWHATEVER.properties" is not in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

property files might be missed in test directory, property files may be used in src directory for log4j, database and application specific purpose. the junit tester will refer the propety files from test/resources directory. so those are all properties should be keep in test directory(whatever the property file needed to run the application, those property file should be there in test resource directory while running junit test).